# Windows 8.1 + DNSCrypt + Unbound for DNS Cache

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I'm following this guide (http://yvoinov.blogspot.it/2014/05/windows-7-unbound-dnscrypt.html) and others but nothing:

I have Windows 8.1 x64, DNSCrypt 1.4.3, Unbound last version downloaded from the site.

I started DNSCrypt on 127.0.0.1:53, changed my DNS setup in network card to 127.0.0.1 and I set this in service.conf of Unbound:

```
# Unbound configuration file on windows.
# See example.conf for more settings and syntax
server:
    # verbosity level 0-4 of logging
    verbosity: 4

    # if you want to log to a file use
    logfile: "C:\unbound.log"

    prefetch: yes
    prefetch-key: yes
    minimal-responses: yes
    do-ip4: yes   
    do-ip6: no  
    do-udp: yes
    do-not-query-localhost: no

    local-zone: "example.com" redirect
    local-data: "example.com A 127.0.0.1"

forward-zone:  
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 127.0.0.1@53

server: auto-trust-anchor-file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unbound\root.key"
```

Where I'm wrong?

If I go to example.com the site shows, also if Unbound have to redirect it to 127.0.0.1 as I set it.

This means that Unbound is not correctly configured and not works. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run two services on port 53. One for Unbound and another for DNSCrypt-proxy. You can only bind one port to one service/ application at a time.

The guide posted suggests using port 5553 instead for DNSCrypt-proxy so change the line in unbound.conf to     `forward-addr: 127.0.0.1@5553` and if DNSCrypt-proxy is listening on port 5553 all should work!